# Нахождение цифр в строке и перевод их в числа

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Строку string с целыми числами и символами, разделенными пробелами нужно ввести с клавиатуры. Далее следует "вытащить" из этой строки все числа, записать их в массив типа int и работать уже с ним. Проблема вот в чем: никаких конкретных целых чисел нет. Они могут быть абсолютно любыми, так что find скорее всего не подходит для решения этой задачи. Подскажите можно ли как-то "вытащить" из строки только числа, а буквы не трогать?

Я думаю написать функцию, которая бы находила символы от '0' до '9' и записывала их в отдельную строку, а затем уже ее переводила в числа с помощью atoi. Однако что если есть строка, например, "0 аАа 9р9 129 1 й12" как сделать так чтобы программа записала ее в виде "0 99 129 1 12", то есть убрала все буквы верхнего и нижнего регистра? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: нет, "12" тоже должно входить в строку

Comment: Если вместо `atoi()` воспользуетесь функцией [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), то можно не копировать символы в буфер. Ищете в цикле не пробел, вызываете эту функцию, анализируете результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача состояла в том, чтобы перевести строчную матрицу содержащую данные, введенные с клавиатуры в матрицу типа double. Спустя несколько дней мне удалось написать верный код. Вот собственно он:

```
        #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
        #endif
        #include "pch.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <clocale>
        #include "stdio.h"
        #include <string>

       using namespace std;
       int main() {
       char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

      cout << "Введите 6 строк массива А. Каждая строка состоит из 4 вещественных чисел, разделенных пробелом." << endl
      << "Ожидание ввода..." << endl;
       char A[1000];
       double dA[6][4]{};
       char*Endptr;
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
           gets_s(A);
           char *strnum = strtok(A, " ");
           int j = 0; 
           while (strnum != NULL){
              dA[i][j] = atof(strnum);
              j++;
              strnum = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
        }
       for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++) {
         for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
              cout << dA[m][n] << ' ';
         }
       cout << endl;
       }

return 0;
}
```

Программа переводит строчную матрицу, заполненную строками наподобие "1,5 14,7 17,9 9,01" в числовую, но разделителем "дробных чисел" должна быть запятая, думаю дело в локали. Возник следующий вопрос: как написать на основе этого кода функцию, чтобы можно было вызвать ее и работать с подобными матрицами?

Comment: `Задача состояла в том, чтобы перевести строчную матрицу содержащую данные, введенные с клавиатуры в матрицу типа double` - а почему тогда в вопросе описана не задача, а какая-то **рня?

Comment: В вопросе описана часть задачи. Если удастся перевести одну строчку, то на основе этого кода можно думать и над целой матрицей. Код который я привел легко можно адаптировать под перевод одной строки..

Answer (score 1):

В соседнем ответе показан подход в лоб.

Вот другой вариант, в стиле <s>нечитаемых однострочников</s> *modern C++*™.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> foo(std::string str)
{
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        [](unsigned char ch){return !std::isspace(ch) && !std::isdigit(ch);}), str.end());
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<int> ret;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = foo("0 аАа 9р9 129 1 й12");
    for (int it : vec)
        std::cout << it << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Вряд ли такой разбор (реализация remove) можно считать разумным, хотя он в точности соответствует желаниям (неразумным) вопрошающего

Comment: @avp *"Вряд ли такой разбор ... можно считать разумным"* Под разумностью имеется в виду эффективность? Если да, то соглашусь. :) Не очень быстро, зато код (относительно) короткий и простой.

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду, что глупо делать разделителями чисел все символы (хоть бы знак минус оставили -)). То, что так в ТЗ я понимаю, но все равно это бред

Answer (score 0):

Скопировать все цифры в буфер, а потом, при нахождении пробела, буфер сконвертировать в число

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> parseString(const char * str) {
    char buf[16];
    int idxBuf = 0;
    vector<int> vec;
    while (true) {
        char curChar = *str;
        switch (curChar) {
            case '\0': 
            case ' ':
              if (idxBuf != 0) {
                  buf[idxBuf] = '\0';
                  int num = atoi(buf);
                  vec.push_back(num);
                  idxBuf = 0;
              }
              if (curChar == '\0')
                return vec;
              break;
            default:
              if ((curChar >= '0') && (curChar <= '9'))
                buf[idxBuf++] = curChar;
        }
        str++;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = parseString("0 аАа 9р9 129 1 й12");
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone test](https://ideone.com/eGVwkn)